# Need Classic ASP for dynamic declaration of request inputs to add database record

Tags: sql-server, asp-classic, windows-server-2019

**This is for Classic ASP**

I have a webform that submits 64 form inputs for 64 columns - not rows] and that number can increase depending on the number of players. I usually define those variables while filtering their input by using code like:

```
strData1 = cleanName(request("Data1"))
strData2 = cleanName(request("Data2"))
strData3 = cleanName(request("Data3"))
```

Then write to SQLExpress like:

```
SQL = "Insert Into Scores ( [Data1], [Data2], [Data3] ) " & _
"Values ( '" & strData1 & "', '" & strData2 & "', '" & strData3 & "' )"
dbConnection.Execute(SQL)
```

But with 64+ columns that can vary in quantity, a function that dynamically reads all request fields, declares them while filtering them, and then dynamically populates the write/update statement would be 100 times better.

Is this even possible?

Comment: That code looks like this *wide* open to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: classic ASP? hasn't that been old for over a decade?

Comment: Can we please stay on topic.

Comment: On-topic is: use better tools. Newer languages have features such as JSON allowing you to pass a batch of objects to the web server. The web server can then transform them into a data table, and then pass them as a Table Valued Parameter (or using `SqlBulkCopy`) directly to SQL Server as a batch. none of this is possible with Classic ASP

Comment: If you absolutely have to use ancient, unsupported technologies like Classic ASP at least try to use whatever security mechanisms they did support. Use [Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/append-and-createparameter-methods-example-vb) instead of creating your own SQL injection vulnerabilities from concatenating strings to build queries with tainted user data inlined.

Comment: If the form fields have a uniform approach to their naming convention creating a dynamically built update statement for any number of fields shouldn’t be an issue. You have not provided any attempt though, what do you have so far?

Comment: @Charlieface just because Classic ASP is older doesn’t mean it can’t use JSON etc. It just usually requires a lot more work, things like model binding have to be implemented manually. But make no mistake, it is entirely capable it’s just not as plug and play as more modern frameworks.

Comment: OK so now we understand this a little more: 64 "form inputs" is actually a single row of 64 columns. So two parts: you need a way of retrieiving the form inputs, sonds like you want to loop `Request.Forms` this link may help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525985(v=vs.90). And you need a way of dynamically inserting into SQL. Regardless of the clear vulnerability and fragility of such code, you could build it off the request parameter names perhaps. Without seeing more of your code as well as your SQL table structures, it's hard to say.

Comment: So I think it's probably best to split this into two questions: How to retrieve request parameter names and values in ASP Classic? How to build and execute a dynamic SQL insert *safely* in ASP Classic?

Comment: @user692942 see the example code? I did mention 64+ columns. How can than that be better described? If JSON SqlBulkCopy is a solution I would try it but my research says that it does not apply in this case..

Comment: Your example code has *three* columns not 64, I naturally assumed (as did others) that you had 64 requests of three columns each. One thing I can see, judging by your most recent edit: it's a bad denormalization if you have 64 identical columns. This data should be unpivoted into separate rows. This is another reason why it was assumed we were referring to row not columns

Comment: You need to rethink your table design. Somthing like `[Author], [Association], [Game], [Grade], [TeamA], [TeamB], [Year], [Month], [Day]` in one table and a separate table with foreign-key to this containing the other columns (or possibly a few other tables). Look up "First Normal Form"

Comment: Like one table for the match and another for the individual games. That would work and also cater for a varying number of players in each team. Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer to "is this even possible?" is NO!

There is no alternative language or method that could possibly work to cater for 64 columns of varying number and especially not one that can increase the number of columns in this case. While it may be possible to dynamically write a varying number of request inputs by using a loop, retrieving those values in a form that could edit and re-submit would be a horrendous task and no saving on the time/effort that it would take to create a hard-coded routine for each and every request input.

The best solution is the alternative suggested by Charlieface, which is to break the task down by creating a table for "Matches" and a separate table for "Games" that  includes a column for [MatchID] which is the primary key used in the Matches table.

Then the number of players and games played can be limitless and without complex scripting to write and retrieve the data.

Comment: Everything is possible, it’s just asking yourself the question is it practical to do this or is there a better approach. But to be clear, the answer is never "No". Saying such is misleading to others who may stumble across this answer.

Comment: Not sure I understand, when have I said anything about rows? Think you’re mixing me up with someone else.